fetch Facebook public groups using Graph API
I am trying to fetch a random public group's posts in Facebook using playwright,(post information : user name, content and comment section [ username, comment] and I am trying to use Graph api to retrieve the data, but it seems I need a token that will allow me access those endpoints.
How can I get this access token?
I already tried to create an app which doesn't even give me any permissions other then email, and I suppose the token that I can generate using this app is only accessible to my own information or the groups I create or I am the admin of.
At first I tried a fetching using playwright, selector using roles and html structure, but I couldn't fetch all comment section that's why I am trying to do it by accessing endpoint.
Perhaps is there any other method?
